# google charts wrong paint?

Tags: google-visualization

[image]

what is wrong with ratio? (100,200)

[https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p&chd=t:**100,200**&chs=300x120&chl=Hello|World](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p&chd=t:100,200&chs=300x120&chl=Hello%7CWorld)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As marcog explained, by default values over 100 will be truncated to 100, thus causing your api call to be processed in the background as:

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p&chd=t:100,100&chs=300x120&chl=Hello|World

which is why you see a pie chart with two equal pieces. One way to fix this is to add a custom scale to your data series using the chds parameter like this:

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p&chd=t:100,200&chds=0,200&chs=300x120&chl=Hello|World

Note I added a `&chds=0,200` to specify that values can range from 0 to 200.

Another option is to use percentages rather than actual values

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The values need to be between 0 and 100, with values above 100 truncated to 100 ([reference](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/chart/docs/data_formats.html#text)).

Answer (score 0):

Had a quick mess around with the URL. Is it possible there's meant to be a "total" parameter in the URL? Since [3 parameters](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p&chd=t:150,100,200&chs=250x120&chl=Hello|World) just splits it equally into 3 parts...